# Presets with actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is the presets variables and to nav with multiple selections, the code below is not really correct and functions perfectly without errors, however it does not work.
    var aClicked:Boolean = false;
    var yyClicked:Boolean = false;
    var tClicked:Boolean = false;
    var oClicked:Boolean = false;

```
a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething1);
function gotosomething1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
yyClicked = true;
activateT();
}

yy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething33);
function gotosomething33(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
tClicked = true;
activateT();
}

o.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomethinggg);
function gotosomethinggg(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
oClicked = true;
activateT();
}

t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething99);
function gotosomething99(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
aClicked = true;
activateT();
}

function activateT()
{
if (aClicked && yyClicked && oClicked)
{
    t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething99);
}
}

yy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gogogo);
function gogogo(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
yyClicked = true;
activateYY();
}

t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomethingplease);
function gotosomethingplease(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
tClicked = true;
activateYY();
}

o.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoi);
function gotoi(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
oClicked = true;
activateYY();

}

a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, millionare);
function millionare(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
aClicked = true;
activateYY();
}

function activateYY()
{
if (aClicked && tClicked && oClicked)
{
    yy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gogogo);
}
}

t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gp1);
function gp1(event:MouseEvent):void
{   
    gotoAndStop(89);
tClicked = true;
activateA();
}

a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gp2);
function gp2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
aClicked = true;
activateA();
}

o.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gp3);
function gp3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
oClicked = true;
activateA();
}

yy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gp4);
function gp4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
yyClicked = true;
activateA();
}

 function activateA()
{
if (yyClicked && tClicked && oClicked)
{
    a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gp2);
}
}

o.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ooo);
function ooo(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
oClicked = true;
activateO();
}

t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ttt);
function ttt(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
tClicked = true;
activateO();
}

a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, aaa);
function aaa(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
aClicked = true;
activateO();
}

yy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, yyy);
function yyy(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
yyClicked = true;
activateO();
}

function activateO()
{
if (yyClicked && tClicked && aClicked)
{
    o.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ooo);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for what you are looking for:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var btnStates:Array = [false];  // Track states for each button - works w/ any # of btns
var btnCounter:int      = 0;    // Count each Active button
var btnActivateNumber   = 4;    // The number of buttons 
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);  // Click on Anything Event

function btnClick(e:Event):void
{
    var btnIndex = e.target.parent.getChildIndex(e.target);     // Btn Index

    trace("BtnIndex:", btnIndex);   // Make Sure btns are are children of same parent   
    switch(e.target.name)           // Check the name of item Clicked
    {
        case "a":   // Checks that you clicked on button and not something else
        case "yy":  // Each of these cases could be done seperately
        case "t":   // Use descriptive names when possible
        case "o":   // Add additional buttons to track if needed
            if(!btnStates[btnIndex])            // Btn not pressed before
            {
                btnCounter++;                   // Another Button Turned On
                btnStates[btnIndex] = true;     // Track Btn State

                // Add Specific code related to button ie. Animation etc.
                e.target.alpha = .75        // lighten Button
            }
            else        // Use if you want the button to turn off on 2nd press
            {
                btnCounter--;                   // Button Turned Off
                btnStates[btnIndex] = false;    // Btn State Reset for this btn
            }
        break;
        default:
            trace("OtherItemClicked:", e.target.name);  // Something else was clicked
            // If you are getting wrong item when you click on your button
            // You may have a child item in your button you will need to disable.
            // set btnName.mouseChildren = false; or item.mouseEnabled = false;
        break;
    }

    if(btnCounter == btnActivateNumber) // Test if enough buttons are pressed.
    {
        this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);   // CleanUp
        trace(btnActivateNumber,"Buttons Activated");
        // Place Your Navigation Action Code Here
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. I just happened to be working on a Multiple Choice Question Engine today and I used that to start building it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want an action to happen when the 3rd button is clicked, or the fourth?

In any case, you can create a dictionary that has boolean values for each button. The key is the button, the value is set to `true` when that button is clicked. You can then count how many keys are positive in that dictionary to find out when "enough" have been clicked.

Comment: i basically want a navigation action to happen when ALL four buttons are clicked.